# Transpose Dataframe problem: For each df.index and df.column combination create a row in new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, data-transform

I have a data frame that looks like this:

The index of my data frame is the "Dates" column.

```
Dates   3M INDIA LTD    ALKYL AMINES CHEMICALS LTD  AAVAS FINANCIERS LTD    ABB INDIA LTD   ADITYA BIRLA CAPITAL LTD
01-01-2020  1.738819    -0.054496   -0.600676   -0.535873   -1.837524   0.514004    -0.853701   -0.101420   2.192982
02-01-2020  -1.110939   3.668744    1.371749    1.346907    4.367026    2.930212    3.540222    4.080081    1.185880
03-01-2020  -0.862856   0.008598    2.543608    2.104247    0.795136    -0.290943   -0.726246   -1.021898   1.368421
06-01-2020  -2.135963   -1.952790   -2.201474   -2.643822   -4.166667   -2.250709   -1.815881   -2.933202   0.300000
07-01-2020  1.692019    8.431578    -1.116379   0.674114    0.097800    -3.166751   0.677638    -1.873767   0.837922
```

I want to create a new data frame such that for each Date, and Company Name Combination, I'll have 1 row in the data frame.

The resulting data frame will look like this:
**Dates CompanyName Value**
[image]

***How Can I achieve this transformation using python pandas operations?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.set_index('Dates').stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['Dates','Company Name','Value']

df.sort_values(by=['Company Name', 'Dates'])
```

Or

```
pd.melt(df, 
        id_vars=['Dates'], 
        value_vars=[x for x in df.columns if x!='Dates'],
        var_name='Company Name',
        value_name='Values')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.melt` from `pandas` and reshape your dataset. Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, use the following :

```
import pandas as pd
df_reshaped = pd.melt(df,id_vars='Dates   3M')
```

which will give you:

```
df_reshaped
Out[13]: 
   Dates   3M                                           variable                                              value
0  2020-01-01                                          INDIA LTD                                              1.739
1  2020-02-01                                          INDIA LTD                                             -1.111
2  2020-03-01                                          INDIA LTD                                             -0.863
3  2020-06-01                                          INDIA LTD                                             -2.136
4  2020-07-01                                          INDIA LTD                                              1.692
5  2020-01-01                             ALKYL AMINES CHEMICALS                                             -0.655
6  2020-02-01                             ALKYL AMINES CHEMICALS                               3.668744    1.371749
7  2020-03-01                             ALKYL AMINES CHEMICALS                               0.008598    2.543608
8  2020-06-01                             ALKYL AMINES CHEMICALS                                             -4.154
9  2020-07-01                             ALKYL AMINES CHEMICALS                              8.431578    -1.116379
10 2020-01-01                                         LTD  AAVAS                                             -0.536
11 2020-02-01                                         LTD  AAVAS                                              1.347
12 2020-03-01                                         LTD  AAVAS                                              2.104
13 2020-06-01                                         LTD  AAVAS                                             -2.644
14 2020-07-01                                         LTD  AAVAS                                              0.674
15 2020-01-01  FINANCIERS LTD    ABB INDIA LTD   ADITYA BIRLA...  -1.837524   0.514004    -0.853701   -0.101420 ...
16 2020-02-01  FINANCIERS LTD    ABB INDIA LTD   ADITYA BIRLA...  4.367026    2.930212    3.540222    4.080081  ...
17 2020-03-01  FINANCIERS LTD    ABB INDIA LTD   ADITYA BIRLA...  0.795136    -0.290943   -0.726246   -1.021898 ...
18 2020-06-01  FINANCIERS LTD    ABB INDIA LTD   ADITYA BIRLA...  -4.166667   -2.250709   -1.815881   -2.933202 ...
19 2020-07-01  FINANCIERS LTD    ABB INDIA LTD   ADITYA BIRLA...  0.097800    -3.166751   0.677638    -1.873767 ...
```

Note that you can `rename` the newly created columns by adding to the above code:

```
df_reshaped = pd.melt(df,id_vars='Dates   3M',var_name = "newname1", value_name = "newname2")
```